# Who are all the dead marines in Halo: Reach and where did they come from?

Tags: halo

In the final "level" of *Halo: Reach*, *Lone Wolf*, Noble Six is fighting, supposedly in/around the breaking yards. Around him (/her) there are many dead marines. Now, where did they all come from? I get that there are many dead military personnel on Reach, but is there a (preferably canon) explanation for who these dead marines are, where they came from, and how Noble comes to fight his last battle among their bodies?

Comment: Are you referring to the "bonus level" where it is just survival for as long as you can?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [people on the 'net have asked/theorized](https://www.google.com/search?q=halo%20reach%20lone%20wolf%20dead%20spartans%20halo%20nation&ei=nlsVVbGdBJDdoATJw4HgDA#q=halo%20reach%20lone%20wolf%20dead%20spartans%20) about this...

[Halo Nation](https://halo.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_SPARTAN_unit_%28Aszod%29#cite_note-1):

> The team's mission is unknown, but it can be assumed that they were
>   deployed to fend off the Covenant attack on the Aszod territory near
>   the ship breaking facilities. SPARTAN-B312 discovered the bodies of
>   thirteen members of the team during the closing stages of the Fall of
>   Reach. It is possible, though unlikely, that some members survived,
>   as the team's composition is unknown. The team may have included all
>   or part of either Echo or Gauntlet teams, or both, as both teams were
>   present on Reach during the invasion.
>
> These SPARTANs may or may not also be any members of SPARTAN-RED team
>   that was split into four smaller teams (Alpha, Beta, Gamma, and
>   Delta). Any one of the missing SPARTANs from these teams could be any
>   one of these dead SPARTANs. Another possibility is that those Spartans
>   were, as Noble Six, survivors of other squads, and reunited there to
>   fight to the end for Reach.

[Halopedia](https://www.halopedia.org/Thirteen_dead_Spartans):

> Thirteen dead Spartans can be found around the level Lone Wolf.
>
> The bodies are those of presumedly SPARTAN-IIIs and are scattered
>   around the landscape. Their armor is randomized, with different
>   configurations and genders every time the level is loaded. The fact
>   that there are thirteen of them may be a reference to the number
>   seven, as at the end of his/her last stand Noble Six becomes the
>   fourteenth dead Spartan in the area.
>
> The Spartans' mission is unknown. They were assumedly deployed to fend
>   off the Covenant attack on the Aszod territory near the ship breaking
>   facilities. The team may have included all or part of Red, Gauntlet
>   and/or Echo teams, as all three teams were present on Reach during the
>   invasion.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I love reading about the backstory that Halo offers for pretty much all of their scenarios. Thanks, again.